# How do i get screen to execute/load .zprofile when starting a new window?

Tags: zsh, gnu-screen

How do i get screen to execute/load `.zprofile` when starting a new window?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Put

```
shell -zsh
```

in your .screenrc, which will tell `screen` to start zsh as a login shell, which will in turn cause zsh to source ~/.zprofile .